# TypeScript & NodeJS: Exports is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have written my NodeJS JavaScript files with Import/Export syntax and my package.json has `"type" : "module"`

The problem is that after `tsc` builds the code, the transpiled code in `/build/server.js` cannot run. It says `Exports is not defined in ES module scope`

Here's my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es2019" ,
    "module": : "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true ,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "strict": true ,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true ,
    "alwaysStrict": true ,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true ,
    "inlineSourceMap": true ,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true ,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  }
}
```

if I remove `"module" : "commonjs"` and add `"moduleResolution": "Node"`, I get a different error with my imports:

**Cannot find module /build/constants imported from /build/server.js**
The module /build/constants.js does exist, but in my code I'm not adding .js to my imports, so I'm importing it like this `import {CONSTANTS} from 'constants'`.

In a TypeScript file, when importing other TypeScript files, should the imports be like `import {CONSTANTS} from constants.js` or `import {CONSTANTS} from constants.ts` or `import {CONSTANTS} from constants`, which is what I have now.

I'm new to TypeScript. What's the best way to solve this problem I'm having?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution. `"type" : "module"` had to be removed from package.json

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, it just hides it. You need `"type": "module"` for future ESM compatibility. I can't name the number of times TS has choked because I wasn't in this mode.

Answer (score 2):

Updating tsconfig "module" and "target" to "ES6" solved the issue.